# How to reference newtyped key in Opaleye as nullable?

Tags: postgresql, haskell, opaleye

I'm using newtyped keys for all my tables

```hs
newtype Key' a = Key a deriving (Show, Generic, Functor)
type Key = Key' Int64
type KeyR = Key' (Column PGInt8)
type KeyW = Key' (Maybe (Column PGInt8))
$(makeAdaptorAndInstance "pKey" ''Key')
```

I now want to have a nullable referece to such a key in a different table but I'm struggling. How can I reference a key as nullable?

Comment: What's the context for this question? What packages / libraries are you using? What are your imports?

Comment: sorry. The only import needed here except Opaleye is Data.Profunctor.Product.TH  (makeAdaptorAndInstance)

Comment: How about `type KeyN = Key' (Column (Nullable PGInt8))`?

Comment: Okay, so I defined the key like that and the write key as `Key' (Maybe (Column (Nullable PGInt8)))`. Then I ran into: `No instance for (Default QueryRunner (Key' (Column (Nullable PGInt8))) (Maybe Key))`. Is that expected? I just assumed I had done something wrong in defining the types since I thought that default instance would be available to me.

Comment: As @ForestPhoenix says below, you need to convert to `Key' (Maybe Int64)`.

Comment: Also, on the Opaleye side it should be `Key' (Column (Nullable PGInt8))` (no `Maybe` in there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To combine my comments with @ForestPhoenix's answer:

Opaleye allows you to convert `Column PGInt8` into `Int64` when you run the query.

That means it *also* allows you to convert `Column (Nullable PGInt8)` into `Maybe Int64`.

You are wrapping `Column (Nullable PGInt8)` in the `Key'` newtype (for type safety) which gives you `Key' (Column (Nullable PGInt8))`.  That means when you run the query you need to read it as a `Key' (Maybe Int64)`.

Maybe this little table makes the correspondence clearer:

```
Opaleye side                  | Haskell side
----------------------------- | -------------
Column PGInt8                 | Int64
Column (Nullable PGInt)       | Maybe Int64
Key' (Column (Nullable PGInt) | Key' (Maybe Int64)
```

In general:

```
Opaleye side                    | Haskell side
------------------------------- | -------------
Column o                        | h
Column (Nullable o)             | Maybe h
MyNewype' (Column (Nullable o)) | MyNewType' (Maybe h)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help, and for writing this sweet library!

Comment: @TommyEngström You're welcome.  Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Opaleye has a default instance for `Nullable PGInt8` to `Maybe Int64`.

What you are trying to do is converting from `Key' (Column (Nullable PGInt8))` to `Maybe Key = Maybe (Key' Int64)`.

For the default instances to work, you need to either convert

- from `Key' (Column (Nullable PGInt8)))` to `Key' (Maybe Int64)`
- from `Column (Nullable (Key' PGInt8))` to `Maybe Key = Maybe (Key' Int64)`